# Network icon not showing up on the system tray

Tags: windows-7, icons, notification-area

I'm not sure why but my network icon is not letting me connect to the internet because is doesn't exist. I tried to enable it but it is blacked out and is not changeable. This is on windows 7

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Network Location Awareness Service is enabled and running.
See http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2012/12/20/the-network-connection-status-icon.aspx

Comment: Is is saying access denied.